# Searching amongst all answers for a question on Quora

Tags: quora

Is there any way to search amongst all answers for a question on Quora? Some questions have many answers ([example](https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-great-underused-words?share=1)), and the usual  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>F</kbd> won't work as not all answers are loaded (answers are loaded on the flight when scrolling down).